# If US Treasuries at yielding 4-5% right now, why can't I find an ETF that yields that amount?

Tags: united-states, interest-rate, yield, treasury, bond-etf

If US Treasuries at yielding 4-5% right now, why can't I find a 1 month US Bond ETF or 6 month US Bond ETF that yields 4-5%? The best I can find is `SGOV` but it only yields 2%.

Picture of US yields on 3/8/2023 for reference:
[image]

Comment: Hello and welcome to the site. Please consider not using code formatting for non-code highlights. There are plenty of other options to give a term emphasis here https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: @MindwinRememberMonica - your feedback seems counter-intuitive on formatting rules.   Why limit formating to code only?

Comment: @Haroon The code formatting in Stack Exchange uses `<code>` HTML tags, meaning that if you're using a screen reader or other accessibility software, it's going to treat things formatted in that way as code, not formatted text. It's an accessibility issue to use them as generic formatting.

Comment: @MindwinRememberMonica, ChrisHayes: A ticker symbol *is* "code".  It is machine-readable and the exact spelling matters.  You'd actually want a screen reader to treat it in the same way as identifiers (variable names, function names) in computer code.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Over the last 12 months, [SGOV](https://www.morningstar.com/etfs/arcx/sgov/quote) yielded 1.84%, but the current SEC yield (30 days ending on the last day of last month) is 4.41%. If you want to know what a fund or ETF yielded most recently, look at the SEC yield.

[image: SGOV Morningstar Quote 3/8/2023]

Answer (score 12):

The average yield to maturity of SGOV is `4.41%`. The `2%` is the 12-month trailing yield. From https://www.ishares.com/us/products/314116/ishares-0-3-month-treasury-bond-etf:

[image]

---

Note that the average yield to maturity of SGOV is a bit lower than newly issued Treasury bills, as the yield to maturity has been increasing steadily over the past 1 year. From https://ycharts.com/indicators/3_month_t_bill:

[image]

Comment: Do you have a recommendation for an ETF that is more closely tied to the actual 3 month yield than SGOV?

Comment: This might be its own question, but the way these ETFs work, would you expect the minimal return to be at least the the minimum yield of 0-3 month treasuries during the previous 12 week period?  Since theoretically every treasury has rolled over at that point?

Comment: I think you'd just look at the ETF's avg effective duration and look at the yield based on that. Open to being corrected on that.

Comment: @Katsu blend SGOV and SHV

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to immediately capitalize on higher rates, your best bet might actually be a money-market mutual fund in the current environment. These funds have access to the Fed's Overnight Reverse Repo ("ONRRP") facility for parking their excess cash, and as of the most recent rate hike, the ONRRP facility is paying 5.30%.